# AngularJS library urls

Tags: angularjs, shared-libraries, src

Good morning.
I would like to know which site contains urls for angular.js and aungula-ui-router.js ? (The question seems not to exist in stackoverflow.com)

Last year i used "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js" but it seems to no longer work.

So what is the official host for angularjs now ?
I know that angularjs is now an old framework but i have to use it at work.
i woul appreciate some help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is this https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js from the official website https://angularjs.org/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally prefer to use https://unpkg.com

See,

- https://unpkg.com/angular/angular.js
- https://unpkg.com/angular/angular.min.js

Comment: Thank you for this rapid answer.